# Delay Transaction on Roxie

Tags: hpcc-ecl, hpcc

*Scenario*: a client wants to test a scenario where they run a transaction against a Roxie service, and they would like the transaction to take at least 50 seconds before it returns anything. What is a good approach to this?

One idea I had is to maybe use the current time and add 50 seconds to it, and when the current time = current time + 50 seconds, we would let the query continue/resume. Maybe use WHEN(), WAIT(), or something else? Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd like to state that this goes against the very design concept of ROXIE, which has always been about making queries as fast as possible -- usually sub-second response to any/every query. I cannot imagine a real-world scenario where this kind of long-delayed response would be desirable.

With that said, you certainly could experiment with using either the WHEN workflow service or the WAIT function to accomplish this. I can't immediately think of any other way you might do this in Roxie. I'd be interested to hear about the results of your experimentation.

Personally, I would probably just insert the return response delay into whatever GUI frontend you're providing to the query. IOW, I would not "mess around" with Roxie and just delay displaying the returned data to the end-user for however long you choose.

HTH,

Richard

Comment: I agree with Richard that you should incorporate the delay in the GUI front end, but perhaps another alternative would be to EMBED a C++ function or another supported external language to "Sleep" your delay. It's very possible that the ECL Scheduling may not even work with ROXIE as the queries are precompiled.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback. I agree with you on making queries as fast as possible on Roxie. However, to clarify, this was a request from a customer where they wanted to test a bad scenario while doing some integration testing.

I did experiment with the WHEN workflow service and the WAIT function, but they didn't appear to work as I anticipated on Roxie. I then did some more research and learned that using Sleep() works like a charm.

Thanks!